# C++ Code Blocks equivalent option of Java Eclipse's organize imports

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, codeblocks

I've been working on Eclipse for Java for a while now and I recently started using CodeBlocks for C/C++, though what I'm finding frustrating is that I don't know how to 'organize imports' in CodeBlocks. In Eclipse it's CTRL+SHIFT+O, though I'm not sure there's something like that in CodeBlocks. Any ideas how I can accomplish that, or how to find the library name(header) of a function I'm using in CodeBlocks from the program itself?

Comment: No such thing in any C++ IDE I've used (and I've used many)

Comment: However, something similar that works with standard headers is in QtCreator by holding Ctrl and pressing the function name.

Comment: I see... I guess I'll just have to memorize the headers ;D, thanks though

Comment: What do you mean by "organize imports"?

Comment: In Eclipse Java, organizing the imports would write the headers/libraries for me, in C++ that would be like the program to automatically see which headers I use(from my code) and write the "#include"s itself.